# MySQL++ + clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, clang++

Не линкуется простейший пример:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <mysql++/ssqls.h>

sql_create_4(DboUser, 1, 0,
  mysqlpp::sql_int_unsigned, id,
  mysqlpp::sql_varchar, sessId,
  mysqlpp::sql_varchar, email,
  mysqlpp::sql_varchar, password
)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
  conn.set_option(new mysqlpp::SetCharsetNameOption("utf8"));
  conn.set_option(new mysqlpp::ReconnectOption(true));
  conn.connect("testdb", "localhost", "user", "password");
  std::vector<DboUser> rows;
  conn.query("SELECT id,sessId FROM users").storein(rows);
  return 0;
}
```

`clang++-3.8 -DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED -std=c++14 -c main.cpp`

`clang++-3.8 main.o -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient`

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
main.o: In function `void mysqlpp::Query::storein<std::vector<DboUser, std::allocator<DboUser> > >(std::vector<DboUser, std::allocator<DboUser> >&)':                                         
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7mysqlpp5Query7storeinISt6vectorI7DboUserSaIS3_EEEEvRT_[_ZN7mysqlpp5Query7storeinISt6vectorI7DboUserSaIS3_EEEEvRT_]+0x39): undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::str(mysqlpp::SQLQueryParms&)'                                                                                                                                                                         
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Компиляция и линковка с помощью g++ (5.3.1 и 6.1.1) завершаются успехом.

Comment: А пробовали линковать не clang'ом, а gcc? Слинкуется?

Comment: @KoVadim gcc этот код не может слинковать, так как это c++ код а не с. Но g++ вполне справляется (я это указал в последнем предложении).

Comment: gcc - это не компилятор:) это набор компиляторов и инструментов. g++ - это одна с программ, которая входит в gcc (gcc = Gnu Compiler Collection). А мой вопрос был в том, что если компилировать clang, а линковать gcc, то все ок?

Comment: @KoVadim, извиняюсь, вначале не понял вопрос. Нет, такой вариант тоже не проходит. Ошибка та же - `undefined reference to mysqlpp::Query::str(mysqlpp::SQLQueryParms&)`

Comment: может быть бага в clang, а может быть в коде mysql++ в коде есть define для компиляторов. И для clang сделаны неверно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABI у gcc и clang в последних версиях не совместимы. Нужно пересобрать libmysql++ clang'ом и проблемы исчезнут.